# How can I persist the API key I create for the Grafana API?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, grafana

I'm running Grafana on Kubernetes (really Openshift) and it is not mounted to a PVC. I need an API key to access the dashboard API so I can pull some dashboards for reporting on our Kafka cluster. The problem is when I create the API key and Grafana is redeployed the API key is no longer there since it is not being stored in some persistent storage option. Is there a way to persist an API key through configurations passed to Grafana? Or some other way that I can make sure the API key I create is there even after a new deployment?

I thought it might be stored in the sqlite db but when I checked it there were no tables so it doesn't seem to be stored there.

**Edit 1**

I'm using Grafana v5.4.3

Comment: It will be useful to help with appropriate yaml files to easily reproduce your issue. Else, you might not get effective answers. From the minimum information available, to get any key/secret information in your k8's workloads, you'll have to make it available via volumeMounts or as environmentVariables. This way, even if a pod dies and a new one gets provisioned, k8's deployment will ensure any new pod's shall have access to those secrets. Details here - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

Comment: @PruthviKumar the problem has more to do with where the API keys are stored in Grafana. After further digging, it seems they are stored in a Go struct in memory. But I still plan on doing more digging tomorrow. 
I agree that I could use the secrets object to store the key in Kubernetes, but once it is there how will it be implemented in Grafana. The only two mechanisms I know to create API keys is through the UI or thorough the admin API, but that requires an API key to create an API key. Does that clarify the problem I'm trying to address?

Comment: I meant initialized not implemented in the previous comment

Comment: If you're using Grafana v6.2+ api key is stored in database. Before v6.2 it was stored in file. You can view it running `select * from api_key;` (6.2+ version) https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/configuration/#remote-cache

Comment: @KFC_ That's a great suggestion and probably why I thought to look in the sqlite db, but I'm using Grafana v5.4.3. Do you happen to know the location or name of the file for versions before 6.2.x?

Comment: As found here: https://community.grafana.com/t/get-api-key-from-grafana-api/13050 there is no way to view key after it's creation so my previous comment might be misleading.